# C# .NET MVC3 ModelState.IsValid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

Im using JSON to post data from a form and ModelState.isValid() returning false, i put a WriteLine for all incoming data and everything looks fine data wise, is there a way to display model state errors to figure out what is not validating? 
this exact code works fine with other models

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult mobileCreateAction(Trip trip)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("saving");
        DB.Trips.Add(trip);
        DB.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new
        {
            success = true,
            msg = "Success saving trip"
        });
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("invalid model state");
        return Json(new
        {
            success = false,
            msg = "Error saving trip"
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }  
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To get a list of errors in the model state:

```
var errors = ModelState
    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
    .ToArray();
```

Then put a break point on this line and inspect the `errors` variable. It will give you a list of properties on your model with their respective errors.

Comment: Darin when i print errors im getting this value: <>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.Web.Mvc.ModelErrorCollection], any idea what it means?

Comment: That line outputs an array of anonymous objects with two properties (Key and Errors). Try accessing those properties ans print that.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the errors in the ModelState.Values collection. Every value has an Errors collection that contains all the model errors for that property.

```
var errors = from v in ModelState.Values 
             where v.Errors.Count > 0 
             select v.Errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919944/copy-modelstate-errors-to-tempdata-display-them-in-the-view)

Building on @Darin's answer the post linked above provides the code needed to display the 'why' message.

```
 foreach (var obj in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (var error in obj.Errors)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage))
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR WHY = " + error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
```