# Copy ModelState Errors to TempData & Display them In the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate, tempdata

Most of my action methods return PartialViews on success and RedirectToAction results on failure. For that, I would like to copy the model state errors into TempData so I could display them to the user. I've read several questions here on SO and some external links but none of them worked for me... I'm decorating the ActionMethod with `ModelStateToTempData` attribute from MvcContrib, then displaying it as follows in the view: (this is just a prototype)

```
        @if (TempData.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var obj in TempData)
            {
                var errors = ((ModelStateDictionary)obj.Value).Values;
                foreach (var error in errors)
                {
                <div style="position:absolute; background:Black; color:White; top:250px; left:550px;">
                    <span style="margin-bottom:5px; display:block; height:25px;">@error.Value</span>
                </div>
                }
            }
        }
```

Rather than displaying the error itself, I keep getting `System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult`. I know this is all wrong, and eventually I would want to filter the model state errors into a dictionary inside the TempData but for now I just want to have the error string displayed in the view.

P.S: I've tried to do it manually without the MvcContrib attribute, and I got the same result. But I do prefer to use my own code so I could have more control over the whole issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok After trying a million things, I found the answer myself... :)

```
if (TempData["ModelErrors"] == null)
    TempData.Add("ModelErrors", new List<string>());
foreach (var obj in ModelState.Values)
{
    foreach (var error in obj.Errors)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage))
            ((List<string>)TempData["ModelErrors"]).Add(error.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

And in the view:

```
    <div id="validationMessages">
        @{
            var errors = (List<string>)TempData["ModelErrors"];
        }
        @if (errors != null && errors.Count() > 0)
        {
            <div style="position:absolute; background:Black; color:White; top:250px; left:550px;">
                @foreach (var error in errors)
                { 
                   <span style="margin-bottom:5px; display:block; height:25px;">@error</span> 
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here it is inside an ActionFilter:

```
public class CopyModelStateErrorsToTempData : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Only export when ModelState is not valid
        if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Export if we are redirecting
            if ((filterContext.Result is RedirectResult) || (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult))
            {
                if (filterContext.Controller.TempData["ModelErrors"] == null)
                    filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("ModelErrors", new List<string>());
                foreach (var obj in filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (var error in obj.Errors)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage))
                            ((List<string>)filterContext.Controller.TempData["ModelErrors"]).Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I started going down this road, and then read your answer.  I combined them into the following files:

**TempDataDictionaryExtensions.cs**

I created extension methods to do the dirty work on the TempData, because I felt it didn't belong in the Action Filter itself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project.Web.UI.Domain
{
    public static class TempDataDictionaryExtensions
    {
        private const string _ModelStateErrorsKey = "ModelStateErrors";

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetModelErrors(this TempDataDictionary instance)
        {
            return TempDataDictionaryExtensions.GetErrorsFromTempData(instance);
        }

        public static void AddModelError(this TempDataDictionary instance, string error)
        {
            TempDataDictionaryExtensions.AddModelErrors(instance, new List<string>() { error });
        }

        public static void AddModelErrors(this TempDataDictionary instance, IEnumerable<string> errors)
        {
            TempDataDictionaryExtensions.AddErrorsToTempData(instance, errors);
        }

        private static List<string> GetErrorsFromTempData(TempDataDictionary instance)
        {
            object tempObject = instance.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == TempDataDictionaryExtensions._ModelStateErrorsKey);
            if (tempObject == null)
            {
                return new List<String>();
            }
            List<string> tempErrors = instance.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == TempDataDictionaryExtensions._ModelStateErrorsKey).Value as List<string>;
            if (tempErrors == null)
            {
                return new List<String>();
            }
            return tempErrors;
        }

        private static void AddErrorsToTempData(TempDataDictionary instance, IEnumerable<string> errors)
        {
            List<string> tempErrors;

            object tempObject = instance.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == TempDataDictionaryExtensions._ModelStateErrorsKey);
            if (tempObject == null)
            {
                tempErrors = new List<String>();
            }
            else
            {
                tempErrors = instance.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == TempDataDictionaryExtensions._ModelStateErrorsKey).Value as List<string>;
                if (tempErrors == null)
                {
                    tempErrors = new List<String>();
                }
            }

            tempErrors.AddRange(errors);

            instance[TempDataDictionaryExtensions._ModelStateErrorsKey] = tempErrors;
        }
    }
}
```

**TempDataModelStateAttribute.cs**

My original, copied the errors out of `TempData` back into `ModelState` prior to the ActionResult executing via `OnResultExecuting`.  This is a combination of copying them into `TempData` and back out.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project.Web.UI.Domain
{
    public class TempDataModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> modelErrors = ((Controller)filterContext.Controller).TempData.GetModelErrors();
            if (modelErrors != null
                && modelErrors.Count() > 0)
            {
                modelErrors.ToList()
                           .ForEach(x => ((Controller)filterContext.Controller).ModelState.AddModelError("GenericError", x));
            }
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (filterContext.Result is RedirectResult
                    || filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
                {
                    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var obj in filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Values)
                    {
                        foreach (var error in obj.Errors)
                        {
                            errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    ((Controller)filterContext.Controller).TempData.AddModelErrors(errors); 
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously consider this concept: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#prg

Comment: What concept? Could you be more specific please?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement concept/pattern called PRG (Post/Redirect/Get). Following link i have provided or checking MvcContrib project on CodePlex should give you a nice explanation of Pattern itself plus implementation examples